# AWS Config rule evaluation result retention time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-config

I'm observing inconsistent behavior w/ the [`GetComplianceDetailsByConfigRule`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/APIReference/API_GetComplianceDetailsByConfigRule.html)  API.

For account `A1`, I have two rules, `R1` & `R2`, which are applied to EC2 instances. Calling `GetComplianceDetailsByConfigRule` for each, I get evaluation results for `R1` that includes instances no longer extant (i.e. historical results), while for `R2` I do not.

Is there some evaluation result retention policy that can be configured per-rule which causes this difference?